# Request Timeout Exception Post DNN8 Upgrade

Tags: asp.net, http, dotnetnuke

We are in the process of upgrading our website from DNN 7.4.0 to DNN 8.0.3.  After I run the upgrade installation and try to access the site, I get error 500.22 dealing with IIS Integrated Mode compatibility.  This turned out to be some issues with the new web.config which I resolved.

However, now when I try to access the site with the new config file I get a seemingly infinite compile time.  No matter what I set the maximum request time value to, it runs for that long and then I get the following request timeout exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Request timed out.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0
```

Does anyone have any idea what causes this, or even where to begin troubleshooting?  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks,

Henry

Comment: are there any logs generated in the portals/_default/logs folder?  That is where I would look first.